# Back icon in react-navigation header goes back to previous StackNavigator using StackNavigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've found when using nested StackNavigators, the default back button in the react-navigation (v1.5.11) header goes back to the previous StackNavigator. For example, consider the following:

**The first level StackNavigator (used within a TabNavigator)**

```
export const NotebookStack = StackNavigator({
  NotebookMain: {
    screen: NotebookContainer,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'My Notebook'
    },
  UserFavorites: {
    screen: FavoritesStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarVisible: false,
      swipeEnabled: false,
      title: 'My Favorites',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontFamily: 'WorkSansLight',
        fontWeight: '200',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**FavoritesStack used in the above first level StackNavigator**

```
export const FavoritesStack = StackNavigator({
  FavoritesSearch: {
    screen: FavoritesSearchContainer
  },
  FavoritesFilters: {
    screen: FavoritesFiltersSlim
  }
}, { headerMode: 'none' });
```

When navigated to the 'FavoritesFilter' route, and the phone's back button is pressed, it navigates back to the 'FavoritesSearch' route. However, when the default back icon in the header is pressed, it navigates back to 'NotebookMain' in the previous stack.

Is this difference in back behavior intended based on the phone's back button vs the default header's back icon?

Comment: for reference : I'm add `onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}` instead of nothing at `headerLeft` for navigating into previous `StackNavigator`

Comment: Yeah - I noticed that as a workaround in some random posts after some searching. Very odd that the default behavior differs based on the button pressed. I tracked back this behavior being introduced by this PR: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/3362 - reverting that change gets both back methods (icon vs device button) working the same - going back one screen.